# Can't install Open CAS on Ubuntu error in "make" command

Tags: ubuntu-23.10

I'm not an expert in this matter and I'm kinda new to linux and OpenCAS. It's for my university project. I'm trying to install OpenCAS with these commands in this exact order:

sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential
git clone https://github.com/Open-CAS/open-cas-linux
cd open-cas-linux
git submodule update --init
python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
sudo su
./configure
make
make install

I do every step without any problem until the make command. It's giving me a long error, I attached a screenshot. Could someone help me?
Ubuntu Version : 23.10 Mantic
Kernel Version : 6.5.0-13-generic

I haven't tried anything cause I don't know what the problem is.